# Windows Phone button press not doing any press when using Phone Accent Brush

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have buttons that are using the Brush Phone Accent Brush and when I press them they don't do the normal button animation. I have changed the ClickMode to all 3 options and no difference.
Is this working as intended then? 
here is button xaml

```
<Button x:Name="FishClear" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="78" Width="108" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
<Button x:Name="FishAdd" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="362,12,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="78" Width="108" Click="FishAdd_Click" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new template for the Button and change the color there.

In blend, select your button, click the menu item "Object"->"Edit Template"->"Edit a Copy..." and a new template is created. Change tke background color for the Normal state.

Comment: What can i do if i have created a button progrmatically ?

Comment: no problem, create a new template this way, give it a name and then assign it to the button in code